# How to handle the push data

Tags: asp-classic, foursquare

I dont understand the explanation on the website.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

I am working with classic asp, do they refer to a query string or a form when they say parameter.

I received the following error; Your Server returned: 502 Bad Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad gateway means that your script is trying and failing to connect to an external url

Comment: I changed the code and now I dont receive an error but I dont receive any values inserted in my database either.

Comment: rather than "Set objAddC = objConn.execute(SQL)", have you tried just "objConn.execute(SQL)".  You don't need to create a recordset for an insert query.  Also, if you comment out the instances "on error resume next" you might get some debug text which will help you pinpoint your problem.